# Server Error in '/webvalidators' Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, rangevalidator

The value `'12/31/2010'` of the MaximumValue property of 'RangeValidator1' cannot be converted to type 'Date'

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox6"
                        ErrorMessage="RangeValidator" MaximumValue="12/31/2010" MinimumValue="12/31/2000"
                        Type="Date" Width="152px"></asp:RangeValidator>​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try formatting as "31-12-10" (Day-Month-Year)

Comment: The issue was (Day-Month-Year). Thanks!